# Relationship between fractal dimension and Hurst exponent

Tags: fractals

For many basic random processes (like [fractional Brownian motion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_Brownian_motion)) [Hurst exponent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurst_exponent) "H" and [fractal dimensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractal_dimension) ( Hausdorf  =  Minkoswki typically) "D" 
are realated by simple formula D = 2-H.
I want to clarify what are exact statemetns known about this relationships.

Consider some function y = f(t) (not a random process, but just function).
Assume that fractal dimensions of its graph equals to "D".

> Is it true that Hurst exponent is somehow correctly defined and equals to H=2-D ?

There possibly can be some subtleties defining the Hurst exponent.
Let me try to give the following precise definition. Assume function f(t) is defined on the interval [0, 1]. Let us look on the values of function at points t=k/n, k=0...n.
So we obtain discrete time series f_0, ...,f_n.
And use  the standard way of calculating the [rescaled range](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rescaled_range) $(R/S)_{n}$,
and existence of the Hurst exponent  means that  $(R/S)_{n}$ ~ $C n^H$.
I am not quite sure this definition is the correct one, but I think it can be suitable modified.

Comment: Do you want your function to be continuous?

Comment: @Goldstern Yes, I mean continuous.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> In principle, fractal dimension and Hurst exponent are independent of
>   each other: fractal dimension is a local property, while the
>   long-memory dependence characterized by the Hurst exponent is a global
>   characteristic. For self-affine processes, the local properties are
>   reflected in the global ones, resulting in the celebrated relationship
>   $D+H=n+1$ between fractal dimension $D$ and Hurst exponent $H$ for a
>   self-affine surface in $n$-dimensional space.
>
> More generally, local and global behavior are decoupled. Stochastic models of the socalled **Cauchy class** separate fractal dimension and Hurst exponent and allow for any combination of the two parameters, without any linear relation.

[Stochastic Models That Separate Fractal Dimension and Hurst Effect](http://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0109031), Tilmann Gneiting and Martin Schlather (2001).

Comment: For info: The Gneiting and Schlather paper was published in SIAM Review, 2004: http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/S0036144501394387